# Limit of a function f and limit of 1/f

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a question I've been pondering for a while,  but did not succeed at proving it. It is as follows:
if a function $f(x)$ satisfies that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$, then is it true that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{L}$, with $L\neq 0$?

I've tried to prove it with the $epsilon-delta$ definition but I couldn't reach any conclusion. Can somebody help me please.

Comment: It is true and you can prove it using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition. You have to make some somewhat «messy» estimates however. I think you can find the proof in several calculus textbooks.

Comment: http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/GenericLimitLawProofs04.htm 

This page might be of help.

Comment: $\frac{1}{f}-\frac{1}{L}=\frac{L-f}{f\cdot L}$. FRom here, maybe you can get

Answer (score 0):

Here is an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Apply the definition of $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=L$ with $$\varepsilon' = \min \left\lbrace \frac{|L|}{2}, \varepsilon \frac{L^2}{2} \right\rbrace$$

which is $>0$ because $L \neq 0$. You get that there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that for every $x \in [a-\alpha, a+\alpha]$, one has $|f(x)-L|\leq \varepsilon'$, which means that for every $x \in [a-\alpha, a+\alpha]$, one has
$$|f(x)-L|\leq \frac{|L|}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad |f(x)-L|\leq \varepsilon \frac{L^2}{2} \quad \quad  (*)$$

In particular, the first inequality gives that for every $x \in [a-\alpha, a+\alpha]$, $$|f(x)| \geq \frac{|L|}{2} \quad \quad (**)$$
which implies that $f$ does not vanish on $[a-\alpha, a+\alpha]$. You can then write that for every $x \in [a-\alpha, a+\alpha]$, $$\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{L} \right| = \frac{|f(x)-L|}{|f(x)|\times |L|}$$ so using both inequalities $(*)$ and $(**)$, you have $$\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{L} \right|\leq \frac{\varepsilon \frac{L^2}{2} }{\frac{|L|}{2} \times |L|} = \varepsilon$$

and you are done.

Comment: How did you get $**$?

Comment: @UriToti By applying triangle inequality in $$|f(x)-L|\leq \frac{|L|}{2} $$

Comment: Yes but the triangle inequality is for $|a+b|\leqslant |a|+|b|$, how can you apply it to a difference?

Comment: There is also the important fact, in triangle inequality, that $$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$$